What would the value of this PDF be at $x = 10$?
I have the following question:
PDF of X

I am really confused on what the value would be at $x = 10$?
From what I understand about the unit step function:
$$u(x) = 1, x>=0$$
$$u(x) = 0, x<0$$
The left term will exist between $3 \leq x<10$. Going by that logic, at $x = 10$, the left term will vanish, and the value of $f(x)$ will be $\frac{95}{144}$. That means $f(x)$ has a jump at $x=10$ of $\frac{95}{144} - \frac{10-3}{72}$.
However, when I look at the solution, they calculated the CDF (which I did, too), and found the jump as $\frac{95}{144}$:
CDF of x and jump


Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

The left term shall vanish, but the right term shall still contain a Dirac delta factor. 
$$f_{X}(10) = 0+\dfrac{95}{144}\,\boldsymbol\delta(10{-}10)$$
This is a constricted function that represents an infinite spike which integrates to one over continuous intervals containing that point.
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(10)\,\mathrm d x&=\dfrac{95}{144}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \boldsymbol\delta(0)\,\mathrm d x \\[2ex] &=\dfrac{95}{144}\end{align}$$
This indicates that there is a point mass at $X=10$; that the cumulative probability function shall jump by $95/144$ at that point.

Yes: the probability density $f_X(10)$ is not finite but the probability $\mathbb P(X=10)=\frac{95}{144}$
